# is it safe to use method that accesses self in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Given the method

```
-(void) doSomeWork
{
  self.abc = ...
  self.doreme=...
}
```

is it safe to use `doSomeWork` inside of a block? as

```
[weakSelf doSomeWork];//this is inside a block
```

Of course my concern is the fact that `doSomeWork` itself has some reference to self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely safe to use `doSomeWork` inside a block with `weakSelf`.

> Of course my concern is the fact that `doSomeWork` itself has some reference to `self`.

A better way of putting this would be "`doSomeWork` itself uses `self`", so as to remove the word "reference" from the sentence. There is no "reference" to `self` created inside `doSomeWork`: the method refers to `self` "for free" by virtue of being an instance method of the class. The actual reference is passed to the method by the caller; it is called `self` when the method is executing, but no new object is created. In other words, when you call `[weakSelf doSomeWork]`, your `weakSelf` becomes `self` inside `doSomeWork` for the duration of the method call.